# Problem with catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of my teamates can't compile our school project. The catkin_make command give this error :

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.topological_order import topological_order" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.packages
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
```

We compared our PYTHONPATH and we have the same :

```
/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

We tried to reinstall ROS completely, but it doesn't work even after that.

Any suggestion to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56873/problem-with-catkin_make/) by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-03**:
Did you do `sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg`? It should tell you that it's already installed.

**Comment by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on 2013-03-03**:
Yes we dit.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-03**:
And if so, make sure there is no old version of catkin_pkg in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

**Comment by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on 2013-03-03**:
What should we do? Delete catkin_pkg in  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-03**:
Yes, delete any catkin stuff in `/usr/local`.

**Comment by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on 2013-03-03**:
There's nothing : (. His ubuntu install is almost pristine too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
2. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin*
3. sudo dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg

This shows you where apt installed catkin_pkg to, this one should be found.

3. python -c 'import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.**file**)'

This shows you where it actually finds catkin_pkg, if it is different from the above, delete the folder

4. python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'

This shows you all places where it looks for catkin_pkg

UPDATE:

python2.7 finds the installed code at /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7, As explained by @joq. if you do not see catkin_pkg folder in there, you need to

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oferbtl](https://answers.ros.org/users/7541/oferbtl/) on 2013-10-08**:
Using the above, I found that my catkin_pkg is installed in '/usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg', so I added this to my .bashrc file:
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/pyshared:${PYTHONPATH}

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-10-08**:
The package installs there, but it is not where PYTHONPATH should point. Post-install should have created compiled modules for each python version you have installed, e.g. /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/*. Those should be in your python path automatically.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-24**:
Could reproduce on some machine with electirc and fuerte installed. When running sudo aptitude reinstall python-catkin-pkg, the relay code appeared.

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
@joq, I tried the: "sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg" and it did install the catkin_pkg in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7. However, I checked afterward and did not find that folder in the python search path (python also failed to import the catkin_pkg).
I manually appended the path to the PYTHONPATH and python succeeded to find the catkin_pkg. However, I hesitate to change the PYTHONPATH and was hoping that the post install adds it to the search path, but it doesn't seem so. Is it supposed to? what could be wrong? I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-12-18**:
That should be in your PYTHONPATH. Did you source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash correctly? What does `echo $PYTHONPATH` show?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
catkin_pkg is a system package - not a catkin package. It is not necessary to source any setup file nor does the PYTHONPATH need to be set.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
@Mo please consider posting the output of the commands (especially 3, 4 and 5) @KruseT has mentioned in his answer for further help.

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
Thanks for the reply. I source the setup.bash since afterward I want to catkin a workspace. Below are the variables and python search path. Please note this is running on a test server (travis).
*** Sourcing ROS setup: /opt/ros/hydro
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
***PYTHONPATH: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
***Python search path (sys.path):
['', '/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
This thread raises a similar issue (read through comments) with no resolution: http://answers.ros.org/question/44669/fuerte-no-module-named-rospkg/

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
Your comment is unreadable. Please update your original question with the information and format them to be readable.

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
I am sorry about that (I am not sure how to format it so it looks better). Anyway, here is the PYTHONPATH after sourcing setup.bash: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
You are using a virtualenv. You might need to install catkin_pkg into your virtual environment in order to be findable.

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
And here is the sys.path: ['', '/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk'...

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
Thanks @Dirk, that might be it. Would installing through pip do it?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
Yes.......

**Comment by [Mo](https://answers.ros.org/users/10056/mo/) on 2013-12-18**:
Thanks. Yes, you are right. I was not aware of the test server running the setup script in a virtual env. I used pip install and that did it.